# Python Logging Module when dynamically creating imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-logging

I am currently using the logging python module to log debug statements when writing my python application.

Everything is working great until I need to log statements from dynamically import python modules.

The python application I am making executes python scripts and returns the results from those said python scripts. Think of it as a test runner and its running test scripts. The test scripts however are determined at run time via a file. Thus, to run the scripts in the runner I am importing them dynamically with importlib.

At this point everything works great however I notice some issues with the logging module. Since I am importing the code at run time rather then statically (statically = the beginning of the python module). It "seems" the logging module on the main_script stops, while the side_script creates a new logging module. Then the new logging modules erases my log file due to having the handler writing to the log rather then appending (by design).

A interesting note is that as soon as I import another module in a function "classically" `import Side_Script # NOT at the beginning of the file` or dynamically the Logging module gets restarted and my current log file is deleted due to the write permissions. Regardless if I run the python import or not. So I am pretty sure it is not from importlib.

I am not sure exactly what is going on. Is it possible to keep the same logging module throughout dynamically created modules in functions?

I created a basic example that demonstrates my problem. Note this is not my actual application, in my application the modules being imported are known at run time via a file.

Main_Script.py

```
import logging.config
import importlib

logging.config.fileConfig('Log_Config.conf')

logger = logging.getLogger('simpleExample')

def main():
    logger.info("Logging in the main script.")
    Test_Modulue = importlib.import_module('Side_Script')
    Results = Test_Modulue.Run_Script()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Side_Script.py

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('Log_Config.conf',disable_existing_loggers=False)

logger = logging.getLogger('simpleExample')

def Run_Script():
    logger.info("Logging in the Side script.")
```

Log_Config.conf

```
[logger_simpleExample]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleDebugCasual,fileHandlerDebugCasual,
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[handler_consoleDebugCasual]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=SummaryFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandlerDebugCasual]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=SummaryFormatter
args=('Debug_Log.txt','w')

[formatter_SummaryFormatter]
format=%(filename)s-%(lineno)d %(levelname)s: - %(message)s
```

Current Log Output:

```
Side_Script.py-8 INFO: - Logging in the Side script.
```

Ideal Log Output:

```
Main_Script.py-8 INFO: - Logging in the main script.
Side_Script.py-8 INFO: - Logging in the Side script.
```

Is there anyway to keep the same logger like they do in pythons example?
https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules

Hope that is enough detail.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're loading the config twice? Also, you're including `disable_existing_loggers` in the module, but not in the main, even though the call in in the main will occur *after* the call in the module.

Comment: Hey @Grismar, So that was the issue! I was rereading the logger configuration.   Ironically the code I had worked on imports from the beginning the file which never gave me a problem. So the order of operations did not overwrite the other files.  Per the example from the python website I gave in the post, I just changed to `import logging` and got rid of the config file and it works.. Sometimes the answer stares right in front of you... Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome - help someone else if you find the opportunity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I was dumb dumb.

Thanks to @Grismar he discovered I was loading the config twice which overwrote my logging module. This then delete my log since it was a fresh new module.

Thus the modification of the code would be the same besides the Side_Script.py which would be:

Side_Script.py

```
import logging.config

logger = logging.getLogger('simpleExample')

def Run_Script():
    logger.info("Logging in the Side script.")
```

And the Output is now:

```
Main_Script.py-8 INFO: - Logging in the main script.
Side_Script.py-8 INFO: - Logging in the Side script.
```